# An error has occurred. 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' Return to Control Panel?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, articles, joomla-3.9, easyblog

I have been trying to add a new **post** from few days using the EasyBlog component in my Joomla 3.9.24 site, but I am getting anerror after clicking the add new button from the Joolma backend.

I can't even edit the existing one!

[image: error image]

I tried many solutions online, but nothing works! Has anyone else faced this issue? What is the solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback.

Comment: @manikanta-gowda did you find any solution to this?